# PostgreSQL - add a constraint that is applied only when the columns are not NULL

Tags: postgresql

How can I create a UNIQUE constraint of multiple columns, that is applied only when the columns are not NULL? So assuming that I create a constraint for column a and b, `1 2` and `1 2` cannot co-exist but `1 NULL` and `1 NULL` can exist together.

Comment: C'mon, you could really have tried a simple standard unique constraint and found that it already does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, adding a unique constraint across the two columns would, by default, allow entering `(1, NULL)` twice.  The reason for this is that `NULL` is treated as "unknown," and therefore Postgres will treat this as not being duplicate.

[Check the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e391b7cde2c7cc61da43c9ead178a424) to see this working in action.